# Ruby on Rails: prevent new page execute through default application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just beginning to learn Ruby on Rails and I know that every time you create a new page in the `app/assets/views` the pages are rendered out through the `layouts/application` which has the HTML markup and the `<%= yield %>`

But if I want to create a home page with a different page yield (or different layout aside from the default application page), how do I do it so that it won't have to go through that default application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

**Controller Wide**

In your controller, you can use the `layout` method

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :name_of_my_layout
end
```

This will use `app/views/layout/name_of_my_layout.html.erb` as the layout for all actions under `MyController`

You can also pass a method to `layout` which returns the name of the layout

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :random_layout

  private

  def random_layout
    %[layout1 layout2 layout3].sample
  end
end
```

The method `random_layout` determines that layout to be used by an action under `MyController` per request.

**Per render**

You can override the above option by passing the `layout` option to render calls.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :name_of_my_layout

  def index
    ...
    render layout: false # no layout
  end

  def new
    ...
    render layout: 'my_super_duper_layout_for_the_new_action'
  end
end
```

**Naming Convention**

You can use the name of the controller as the name of the layout.  For example you have a posts controller, if you have an `app/views/layouts/posts.html.erb`, rails will use this instead of `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` if you have not specified a layout in your controller.

Comment: whats the difference between having a colon `layout :name_of_my_layout` to quotes `layout 'name_of_my_layout'`?

Comment: Also, why does render layout have to be the last syntax code before end within a method?

Comment: there's no difference with using a string and a symbol when you pass it to `layout`.  I haven't looked at the code for `layout` yet but I'd bet it just uses that parameter to set the filename of the layout so it probably converts the passed parameter to string.

Comment: passing render may not always be the last thing you call but it's good practice to do it so you know what the action will do.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you have a controller, you can set the layout:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout 'my_layout'
end
```

and that will make all the actions of the controller **HomeController** to render the layout "app/views/layouts/my_layout.html.erb", instead of the default layout.

You can also specify a layout for an action, like:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render layout: 'my_layout'
  end
end
```

or to not use a layout at all:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

you can find more information about rails and layouts [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)